# The incoming event is not a valid request from Amazon API Gateway or an Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I created a REST API with AWS API Gateway. I have a GET method that triggers a Lambda function, but I cannot get the response I need. I properly configured query params etc. but in Lambda logs I see this.

```
com.amazonaws.serverless.exceptions.InvalidRequestEventException: The incoming event is not a valid request from Amazon API Gateway or an Application Load Balancer

2021-05-19T15:37:38.003+04:00   at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.AwsProxyHttpServletRequestReader.readRequest(AwsProxyHttpServletRequestReader.java:48)

2021-05-19T15:37:38.003+04:00   at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.servlet.AwsProxyHttpServletRequestReader.readRequest(AwsProxyHttpServletRequestReader.java:30)

2021-05-19T15:37:38.003+04:00   at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.LambdaContainerHandler.proxy(LambdaContainerHandler.java:201)
```

What am I missing ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When running lambdas locally, you need to define the event that trigger it.
For example:
`sam local invoke --event tst\event.json` where the event.json is basically the http parameters you are passing.

```
{
  "httpMethod": "GET",
  "path": "/",
}
```

For creating an event json template file for http requests, you can use: `sam local generate-event apigateway aws-proxy`.